# Why applying Grad-CAM to the input layer is not common?

Tags: neural-networks, artificial-intelligence

Grad-CAM is a popular tool that could be applied to the last convolutional layer to understand the inner structure of the deep neural network.

It is general to apply Grad-CAM onto the last convolutional layer of the deep neural network when image classification, and use cv2.resize or various interpolation methods to adjust Grad-CAM with the size of the last convolutional layer to the size of the input layer.

If Grad-CAM is applied to the input layer, not only will it be possible to prevent unclear activation map due to the interpolation, but also more clear and direct Interpretable A.I. could be achieved.

Then, why do people apply the Grad-CAM only onto the last convolutional layer, not onto the input layer directly, rather than resizing? Is there any specific reason to do so?

Comment: Can you add a link or reference for Grad-CAM?

Answer (score 0):

Gradcam explains the layer, you apply it to. Upper layers (like the last convlayer) detect semantically meaningful objects, lower layers detect things like basic shapes, e.g., edges. So if you want to explain why a network sees an object, e.g., a "cat", using an upper layer will highlight the actual object. Lower layer will (not always but quite often), highlight a lot of thing unrelated to the object.